# How can I concatenate endnotes in a Word doc paragraph?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a *.docx file with more than 4000 endnotes. My task is to combine endnotes inside every paragraph (where there is 3 and more endnotes) to one big endnote.

For example.

Input:

word word{1} word{2} word word{3} word.

Endnotes:

{1} endnote

{2} endnote

{3} endnote

Output:

word word word word word word{1}.

Endnotes:

{1} endnote; endnote; endnote

So I'll have one big endnote instead of several small ones.
What I have tried:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As String
Dim tmp As String

tmp = ""
For i = 1 To Selection.Endnotes.Count Step 1
    t = Selection.Endnotes(i).Range.Text
    If tmp = "" Then
        tmp = Selection.Endnotes(i).Range.Text
    Else
        tmp = tmp & "; " & Selection.Endnotes(i).Range.Text
    End If
Next i

For i = Selection.Endnotes.Count To 1 Step -1
   Selection.Endnotes(i).Delete
Next i

Selection.Expand wdParagraph

ActiveDocument.Endnotes.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:=tmp
End Sub
```

It works but a user must select proper paragraph by hand. What I don't know is how to do this process automatically - find bad paragraphs with more than 3 endnotes and apply the code above to these paragraphs. ActiveDocument.Paragraphs item don't have Endnotes property.
Please help)

Comment: Why aren’t you using Intellisense, the Object Browser, or the online help? Those tools built-in to the VBE should be your first source of research. They would have shown you that whilst `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs` may not have an endnotes collection, `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(n).Range` does.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt thank you! I use it, of course, but I couldn't find this property.

Answer (score 0):

So the decision is:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As String
Dim tmp As String
Dim p As Paragraph
 
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
     If p.Range.Endnotes.Count > 3 Then
        tmp = ""
        For i = 1 To p.Range.Endnotes.Count Step 1
            t = p.Range.Endnotes(i).Range.Text
            
            If tmp = "" Then
                tmp = t
            Else
                tmp = tmp & "; " & t
            End If
        Next i

        For i = p.Range.Endnotes.Count To 1 Step -1
            p.Range.Endnotes(i).Delete
        Next i
    
        ActiveDocument.Endnotes.Add Range:=p.Range, Text:=tmp
     End If
Next p
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P - the answer is from the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P it concatenates endnotes as described in my question above.